# xcode NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray, plist, nsdictionary

I'm new to Xcode. what i want is  read plist data locally in my program. i got 
`NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil` error. Here is what i declared and my plist file. Thanks

```
NSMutableArray *phoneArray;

NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PhoneList" ofType:@"plist"];

phoneArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

---

key        type
Item 0     Dictionary
Item 1     Dictionary

Items have  description, name keys as type of String.

Comment: one of youritems in plist is nil...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify your plist, there is most likely a bad value. Items in an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` can not be null. You can use Xcode to open the plist file to verify it.

Personally I use "PlistEdit Pro", it can provide somewhat better diagnostics when the plist is invalid. There is a [Free Trial here](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/plisteditpro/) of PlistEdit Pro.

Comment: Thanks Zaph. Program helps a lot.

Comment: Actually i implemented wrongly plist.  Outer tag is the <array> and inner tags are <dic>. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

The object to add to the array's content. This value must not be nil.

before any input from the plist file, please check to see that the element is not nil, to avoid the excetion

Comment: Thanks WhiteTiger i did with                            NSLog(@"%@",[dic objectForKey:@"Item 0"]);